# TIdTCPClient connection pool

Tags: delphi, tcp, connection-pooling, indy

I want to use `TIdTCPClient` to connect to Redis from a web server application made with Delphi and `TWebModule`.

Currently on WebModule creation I create a new `TIdTCPClient` and connect to Redis, e.g.:

```
procedure TWebService.WebModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);-
begin
    FClient := TIdTCPClient.Create();
    FClient.Connect('REDIS_HOST', 6379);
end;
```

and on web module destroy, I disconnect and free the resource, e.g.:

```
procedure TWebService.WebModuleDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
   FClient.Disconnect;
   FClient.Free;
end;
```

All works... But this way I create a new connection on every new request and after a lot of time there is a growing number of `TIME_WAIT` sockets.

I would like to implement a global connection pool with a fixed number of connections always open (eg.: 50) and use only those.

Has Indy something to manage a pool of TCP connections?

Comment: Normally you would pool at a higher level - like a pool of Redis clients. This is so the common pool functions like testing a connection (to see if it still works) are more specific to what is being pooled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Indy does not provide anything for pooling TCP connections. You will have to implement your own pool of `TIdTCPClient` objects in your own code.

Comment: Hi Remy, I have tried to implement a pool of TCPClient, I need a code review, you can help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67416724/delphi-tidtcpclient-connection-pool-in-a-multithread-environment

Comment: @ar099968 "*I need a code review*" - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: mhh ok, i have also opened a question on code review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/260418/delphi-tidtcpclient-connection-pool-in-a-multithread-environment